# Completion of two metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ be equipped with two metrics, namely $d_1(x,y) = |x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$.

I am looking for the completion of these two spaces.

My attempt:
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any Cauchy-sequence. This means, that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for any $m,n > N, m, n \in \mathbb{N}$: $d(x_m, x_n) < \epsilon$.

In metric one, $d_1$, $0$ is missing, therefore the CS cannot converge. Hence the completion of $(X,d_1)$ must be $\mathbb{R}$.

For $d_2$, we see that $d_2(x_m, x_n) = |\frac{x_n-x_m}{x_m x_n}| < \epsilon$. $x_m, x_n$ are not allowed to be zero, hence the space $(X,d_2)$ is already complete.

Is this correct? Can anyone help me improving my sloppy reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any sequence in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ that (in the ordinary sense) diverges to infinity is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the metric $d_2$. For example, $x_n = (-1)^n n$.

So no, $(X,d_2)$ is not already complete.

To understand the completion of $(X,d_2)$, here is a hint: the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is an isometry from $(X,d_1)$ to $(X,d_2)$.